# Jquery Ajax Call In For Loop Only Runs Once - Possible Issue with Timing & Exit Condition?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, dom

## Background

I'm building a form that uses autocomplete against the EchoNest API.

First the users picks an artist, using the Artist Suggest call.  Next they select a song but the Song and/Or Artist song search doesn't provide a "wild card" search.  It only returns exact matches.  So based on the forums they suggest building an array of the songs and using auto complete on the array.  I can only get a maximum of 100 responses at a time.  I do know based on the initial response the number of songs.

## My Plan:

- Wrap the ajax call in a for loop ('runonceloop').
- Amend the loop exit condition after the first response with the total number of songs.

## Challenge I'm having:

The 'runonceloop' only completes a singe loop because or at least that's what I believe:

- The exit condition is satisfied before the first response <sup>[1]</sup> is received.

I've tried to adjust the 'exit condition' and 'counter' such that they are set and and increased at the end of the success block.  This seems to lock up my browser.

Can someone provide some guidance on this situation?<sup>[2]</sup>

I'd really appreciate it.

I also don't think turning async off is a good idea because it locks the browser.

### Response<sup>[1]</sup>:

```
    {
  "response": {
    "status": {
      "code": "0",
      "message": "Success",
      "version": "4.2"
    },
      "start": 0,
      "total": 121, //Used for 
      "songs": [
        {
          "id": "SOXZYYG127F3E1B7A2",
          "title": "Karma police"
        },
        {
          "id": "SOXZABD127F3E1B7A2",
          "title" : "Creep"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

### Code<sup>[2]</sup>

```
var songsList = [];
function getSongs() {
            var numsongs = 2; //at least 2 runs.
            var startindex = 0;
            runonceloop: //<~~~~Referenced in question
            for (var j = 0;j >= numsongs;) {

                 console.log('numsongs' + numsongs);
                 $.ajax({

                     url: "http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/songs",
                     dataType: "jsonp",
                     data: {
                         results: 100,
                         api_key: "XXXXXXXXXXX",
                         format: "jsonp",
                         name: $("#artist").val(),
                         start: startindex

                     },

                    success: function (data) {
                        var songs = data.response.songs;
                        //This is my big problem.  numsongs for the exit condition isn't being modified.
                        numsongs = data.response.total; //modify exit condition
                        for (var i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
                            songsList.push(songs[i].title);

                        }

                    j +=100;// increase by 100 to match number of responses.
                    }
                  });
}};
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it fit your needs but fixed some of your syntax errors and use a closure:

```
var songsList = [];

function getSongs() {
    var numsongs = 2; //at least 2 runs.
    var startindex = 0;
    runonceloop: //<~~~~Referenced in question
    for (var j = 0; j < numsongs;j++) {
        console.log('numsongs' + numsongs);
        (function(_startindex){
        $.ajax({

            url: "http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/artist/songs",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {
                results: 100,
                api_key: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
                format: "jsonp",
                name: $("#artist").val(),
                start: _startindex

            },

            success: function (data) {
                var songs = data.response.songs;
                numsongs = data.response.total; //modify exit condition
                for (var i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
                    songsList.push(songs[i].title);
                 console.log(songsList);
                }


            }
        });
        })(startindex);
        startindex+=100;
    }
};

getSongs();
```

[DEMO (daft punk)](http://jsfiddle.net/CC3m8/)  {check you console}

Comment: thanks for the fixes.  It runs better now :-) But it actually runs 3 times as it should but doesn't follow the appended numsongs exit condition.

Comment: j <= numsongs should be j < numsongs

Comment: After the first response numsongs should be "121" for the shown example response.  Instead it remains '2'.

Comment: There's a total of 121 results.  I've attempted to adjust it with 'numsongs = data.response.total'  I know that the total is being read correctly from the first json.

Comment: I've commentd in the code to attempt to clarify. See line 3 past the 'success'

Comment: ok, if i better understand what you are trying to do, you want to make only enough requests to get all the songs for an artist. So, i'd say you should first make the request to get total song for an artist then divide this total by 100 (max allowed for each request) and make all necessary requests in the loop using closure for startindex. Rigth now, i'm too tired to see what's going on i'm afraid

Comment: I was considering that method earlier.  I guess I'm just trying to push myself.  I really appreciate your help though.  I've been struggling the past few weekends with this.  If I don't figure it out, I'll def accept your answer.